# Error creating Vector object from csv file in Blender (with python script)

Tags: python, scripting, vector-mapping, vector

I'm trying to create a Vector object (from mathutils library), whereby I have a csv file with 3 columns: x coordinate, y coordinate and z coordinate. All I want to do is import this CSV file in Blender and pass the x,y,z values to the `Vector` object, using python script. This is my code so far:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
from itertools import product
import random

x_size = 512
y_size = 512
z_max = 256

csvfile = open(r'C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Deep-lizard\x_y_z coor.csv')

inFile = csv.reader(csvfile)
# skip header
inFile.__next__()

vertices = [Vector( (float(r[0]), float(r[1]), float(r[2])) for r in inFile]
```

However, when I run this script I get the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\%username%\Documents\new script.blend\Text", line 19
    vertices = [Vector( (float(r[0]), float(r[1]), float(r[2])) for r in inFile]
                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

location: <unknown location>:-1

Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

The csv file content is in this format:

[image]

Not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a *syntax error* (see the error message), remove one of the parenthesis at the beginning of the list comprehension to: `[Vector( float(r[0]), float(r[1]), float(r[2]) ) for r in inFile]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a programming syntax error. It would be better suited for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet is missing the `csv` module import.

```
import csv
```

The **syntax** error is simply a missing closing bracket of the tuple.

```
vertices = [Vector((float(r[0]), float(r[1]), float(r[2]))) for r in inFile]
```

Since you actually know, that you will get a list of three floats, you can import the csv with the `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` argument.

```
inFile = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
inFile.__next__()

vertices = [Vector(r) for r in inFile]
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. Some of these mistakes are so silly like forgetting `import csv`. I can't believe I didn't notice that :S   I just got this other error now: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'y_coord'`, even though I used `inFile.__next__()`, which should've skipped the header. Do you know why it didn't work?

Comment: Does this happen with the first method (manually parsing the floats)?

Comment: In the error it says: `line 17, in <module>`, which is the line: `inFile.__next__()`. Sorry is this what you meant?

Comment: The only way I can resolve it is by changing the line: `csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)` back to just `csv.reader(csvfile)` and the line: `vertices = [Vector(r) for r in inFile]` back to: `vertices = [Vector( (float(r[0]), float(r[1]), float(r[2]))) for r in inFile]`. Thank you for your help in any case. Much appreciated.